How to run code on Windows only in a cross-platform project?
I have a c# project that is targeting net7.0. I have a block code that should only run when running on windows.  And I am developing on Windows. To that end, I've added #if...#endif
#if WINDOWS

using var el = new EventLog("Application");
el.Source = "Application Error";
el.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, 10002);

#endif

However, when I run it locally in Visual Studio 2022, the code inside the block is grayed out and does not run at all.
How do I mark it so that it only runs on windows?

It appears that's only available if you target specific TFMs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives

@Lennart So then I cannot use #if WINDOWS in a standard .net 7 project?    I am trying to avoid if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Windows)) {...}

Do you want to decide when compiling or at runtime?

@KlausGütter It's better at compile time, but I am seeing that there isn't a way to do that.

#if will check the "on what OS the code was built" condition. So, if the code was built on macOS, even if you then run it on Windows after all, the code inside #if will not be executed (it does not exist in the compiled binary at all). If it is exactly what you need - you can play with MSBuild to check the OS at build time and add the corresponding compiler variable. Then use this variable in the #if (I can elaborate if needed). But if you need to distinguish the environment your code run (not  compiled) then #if is a wrong way.

@Serg That makes sense.  So then [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")] attribute on a class still must be guarded by RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform call, correct?

@AngryHacker, generally - yes, but it depends. You may want to add the explicit IsOSPlatform() checks to make the code as reliable as possible. You may also decide, that anyone who ignored the warning and called that code on the wrong OS is fully responsible for the consequences (e.g. program crash) - so, it becomes the caller's responsibility to perform an OS check before the calling your code. You can also use the asserts or other debug-only checks (so, the production checks are on the calling side, but in the debug mode there are additional checks in the your code for the convenience).
